# Trouble it gives me 404 (not found) - After I click on my submit

Tags: javascript, c#, angularjs

This is how I have set up my whole hand to show off content as it should. but when I eg. click submit you will see it with this error

> http://localhost:57298/Opgaver/FindTask/3/Jesper Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

My json is in the correct folder as it should, etc.. Error occurs only when I click submit content

I have not written anything up in my *RouteConfig.cs* file on how it should be in relation to the file and angularjs.

Load.js

```
var app = angular.module('Opgaver', []);
app.controller('OpgaverCheck', function ($scope, $http) {

    //Must make it here when I click submit.
    $scope.CheckValue = function (module) {
        //console.log("Hello world " + module.Id + " - " + module.text);

        //GET
        $scope.$watch("module.Id", function() {
            var url = "/Opgaver/FindTask/" + module.Id + "/" + module.text;

            $http.get(url).success(function (response) {
                //It must give a response back from json it is succe or error.
                $scope.jsonMessage = response;
            })
        })
    }
});
```

When I run my console.log then it's that I want to do.

OpgaverController.Cs

```
[HttpGet]
    public JsonResult FindTask(int Id, string Text)
    {
        var db = Helpers.HelperToTables.DbValue;
        var valuetext = Text.ToLower();

        var check = db.LektionerOpgaves.FirstOrDefault(i => i.fk_LektionerId == Id && i.CorrectAnswer.Equals(valuetext));
        if (check != null)
        {
            //succes
            return Json("Succes");
        }
        else
        {
            //Error
            return Json("Error");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I can see the correct URI for your route (if you didn't modify the default routing inside `RouteConfig.cs`) is the following one:

```
http://localhost:57298/Opgaver/FindTask/3?Text=Jesper
```

That's because the `Text` parameter is not mapped to anything inside the route, and thus it will be mapped as a query string parameter.

If you need to map it inside the route you should create a custom route for your specific mapping, you will find more inside the [official documentation](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/controllers-and-routing/creating-custom-routes-cs).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var url = "/Opgaver/FindTask?Id=module.Id&Text=module.text;
```